Writing into ODS file with AODL C#
My goal is to export information to a table in .ods format. I can't use any commercial libraries (in other words, I'm very limited to free software), so I tried using the AODL 1.2.0.1 library. Initially, I just added it via NuGet, but when I launched the program I got the error “Strong name required.” I decompiled the dll file using ildasm and built it back (signed with the same key that signed my project).
The error with the strong name is gone, but now it gives the error "Access is denied at the path %some path%\aodlwrite\Configurations2". Is there a solution for this error?
I suspect this error is a permissions issue, but I can't do anything on my end to resolve it. My project is class library for exist application (basically is plugin)

Can you [edit] your post with more specifics? What was the name and version of the Nuget pacakge you added? What runtime does your application target? Is your project's assembly signed?

@gunr2171 thank you for answer. i edit my post, about assembly - yes, it's signed, i mentioned it in question
